# WP WooCommerce и shortcode от Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как встроить в WooCommerce вместо кнопки покупки Popup окно с формой связи? Хочу на некоторых товарах поставить Contact Form 7.

Но в WooCommerce можно ссылатся на URL. Как заставить обратится к shortcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берете любое модальное окно (например: [bootstrap_modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals)) и в нём вызываете форму `<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact_form_7_example]'); ?>`

Это ваша кнопка:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- 
    target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>
```

Это ваше модельно окно, например где-то в футере:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact_form_7_example]'); ?>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```